# Sony Camera a6500: How to transfer movies with Remote SDK

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

I'm using a Sony Camera a6500 and the Sony Camera Remote API SDK.

According to the documentation, I could be able to transfer recorded movies with the API with a a6500.
When I'm calling the method getAvailableApiList (after a stat, I've got these methods:

```
0:"getVersions"
1:"getMethodTypes"
2:"getApplicationInfo"
3:"getAvailableApiList"
4:"getEvent"
5:"stopRecMode"
6:"startMovieRec"
7:"startLiveview"
8:"stopLiveview"
9:"setShootMode"
10:"getShootMode"
11:"getAvailableShootMode"
12:"getSupportedShootMode"
13:"setExposureCompensation"
14:"getExposureCompensation"
15:"getAvailableExposureCompensation"
16:"getSupportedExposureCompensation"
```

None of the method useful to list and transfer camera movies are listed (getSchemeList, getSourceList, getContentList, setCameraFunction ...).
I've tried the methods, but I've got an invalid method error (12).

I also try to reach the avContent endpoint, without more success.

Is there another way to transfer a6500 camera files with the remote API ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the solution: You have to update the smart remote application to the last version to have the new methods and new APIs (1.0 to 1.4).

Connect the camera with the Sony Play Memories Camera App Store and update the app. Found in http://briansmith.com/how-to-update-sony-play-memories-camera-apps/